# Compare two columns and find matched rows

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have written a VBA code that matches the 1st column with second column and return the entries of 1st row that are not available in second row. Given below is the sample code which I used in my script.

Now the problem is mathcing of columns not happening correctly, some matched values are also coming in the output. Someone please help me to find where I am incorrect?

```
Dim c As Range, d As Range
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

shPort_Code.Activate
LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To LastRow1
    Set rng1 = shPort_Code.Range("B" & i)

    For j = 2 To LastRow2
        Set rng2 = shPort_Code.Range("J" & j)
        'If rng1.Text='
        If StrComp(rng1.Text, rng2.Text, 1) = 0 Then

            'rng1.Cells("D" & i).Value.Copy Destination:=shPort_Code.Range("J2")
            rng1.Value = Null
        'Else
            'rng1.Text.Select
        End If
    Next j
    If Not Match Then
        Range("J" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = rng1
    End If
Next i
```

Thanks in advance.

Renu

Comment: it would probably help to add some examples of the data as well as the expected and erroneous output

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub compare()

Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer, rowA As Integer,     found As Integer, x As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row *'last row from B*
    LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row *'last row from J*
End With

rowA = 1
found = 0

For i = 4 To LastRow1
    For j = 2 To LastRow2
       x = StrComp(Cells(i, 2).Value, Cells(j, 10).Value, 1)
       If x = 0 Then *'if equal*
            found = 1 *'value from column B is in column J* 
        End If
Next j

If found = 0 Then *'if the value is not in column J*
    Cells(rowA, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value *'copy the value in column A*
    rowA = rowA + 1
Else
    found = 0 *'set found back to 0 for the next comparison*
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code.but its giving me the same output.i dono where i am going wrong.

Comment: You could add here the values so I can see what are you trying to achieve.